# Statusbar in Cordova-ios stays translucent

Tags: ios, cordova, native, phonegap

I am using the cordova status bar plugin and the statusbar is translucent and white. I am developing for iOS 11 witht he newest Version of macOS and xCode.

I researched the errors but none of the fixes proposed helped me.

Adding **viewport-fit=cover** to the meta tag at the index.html did not work.

Adding the **feature tag** with ios-package, as mentioned in the docs, to www/config.xml as a child to widget.

Adding the **preference tag** with StatusBarBackgroundColor and Overlay to the config.xml (as a child to widget and to ios) and www/config.xml did not works.

Using it in **Code** with the StatusBar global var inside a cordova.platformId = 'ios', has no effect.

In the end the app starts with a black bottom, the black bottom is gone and then there is the translucent status bar.

Answer (score 5):

Adding this to my config.xml solved the problem for me:

```
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ffffff" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i have ran into the similar issue, that i neede to my statusbar to overlay the WebView and be white with 50% transparency. So i investigated the plugin code and noticed, that if status bar overlays WebView - then the plugin ingores the background settings.

So the only solution was to fork the original plugin and modify it. You can take it here:

https://github.com/Fomenko-developer/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Installation:

cordova plugin add https://github.com/Fomenko-developer/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git